# Returning a unique string from an Array using Collections?

Tags: android

I am trying to return a "unique" string from an Array of 7 strings. They will be stored into a Database and need to be assigned randomly, so I am using Collections.shuffle to get a random distinct string, or so I thought.

Here is what I am using:

```
    public String RandomNumber()  {
    List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("Mafia", "Mafia", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian");
    Collections.shuffle(roles);
    return roles.get(0);
}
```

I want there to be EXACTLY 2 Mafias, and EXACTLY 5 civilians, but I am getting repeats. Why is that?

(Also, I plan on making it different for a different amount of players rather than exactly 7, if anyone could push me in the right direction in terms of how I could allocate roles depending on number of players (e.g for every 3 civilians, there is 1 mafia)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
 public String RandomNumber()  {
    List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("Mafia", "Mafia", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian");

    TreeSet treeset = new TreeSet();
    treeset.addAll(roles);

    roles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator it = treeset.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Object i = it.next();
        roles.add((String) i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(roles);
    return roles.get(0);
}
```

Comment: I get an UnsupportedOperationException with roles.clear();.

Comment: I still get repeats

Comment: did you add this line roles = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it after getting. Smth like that:

```
public String RandomNumber()  {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Mafia", "Mafia", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian"));
    Collections.shuffle(roles);
    String role = roles.get(0);
    roles.remove(0);
    return role;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method and I get an error using roles.remove(0);... UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Because you didn't copy first line `List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Mafia", "Mafia", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian"));` @TussRamzan

Comment: Because you have repeats in your array? @TussRamzan